# TORQUE jobs hang on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, torque

I have TORQUE installed on Ubuntu 16.04, and I am having trouble because my jobs hang. I have a test script `test.pbs`:

```
#PBS -N test
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -l walltime=0:01:00

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
touch done.txt
echo "done"
```

And I run it with

```
qsub test.pbs
```

The job writes `done.txt` and echoes `"done"` just fine, but the job hangs in the `C` state.

```
Job id                    Name             User            Time Use S Queue
------------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
46.localhost              test             wlandau         00:00:00 C batch
```

## Edit: some diagnostic info on another job from `qstat -f 55`

```
qstat -f 55
Job Id: 55.localhost
    Job_Name = test
    Job_Owner = wlandau@localhost
    resources_used.cput = 00:00:00
    resources_used.mem = 0kb
    resources_used.vmem = 0kb
    resources_used.walltime = 00:00:00
    job_state = C
    queue = batch
    server = haggunenon
    Checkpoint = u
    ctime = Mon Oct 30 07:35:00 2017
    Error_Path = localhost:/home/wlandau/Desktop/test.e55
    exec_host = localhost/2
    Hold_Types = n
    Join_Path = n
    Keep_Files = n
    Mail_Points = a
    mtime = Mon Oct 30 07:35:00 2017
    Output_Path = localhost:/home/wlandau/Desktop/test.o55
    Priority = 0
    qtime = Mon Oct 30 07:35:00 2017
    Rerunable = True
    Resource_List.ncpus = 1
    Resource_List.nodect = 1
    Resource_List.nodes = 1:ppn=1
    Resource_List.walltime = 00:01:00
    session_id = 5115
    Variable_List = PBS_O_QUEUE=batch,PBS_O_HOST=localhost,
        PBS_O_HOME=/home/wlandau,PBS_O_LANG=en_US.UTF-8,PBS_O_LOGNAME=wlandau,
        PBS_O_PATH=/home/wlandau/bin:/home/wlandau/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
        :/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/ga
        mes:/snap/bin,PBS_O_SHELL=/bin/bash,PBS_SERVER=localhost,
        PBS_O_WORKDIR=/home/wlandau/Desktop
    comment = Job started on Mon Oct 30 at 07:35
    etime = Mon Oct 30 07:35:00 2017
    exit_status = 0
    submit_args = test.pbs
    start_time = Mon Oct 30 07:35:00 2017
    Walltime.Remaining = 60
    start_count = 1
    fault_tolerant = False
    comp_time = Mon Oct 30 07:35:00 2017
```

## And a similar `tracejob -n2 62`:

```
/var/spool/torque/server_priv/accounting/20171029: No matching job records located
/var/spool/torque/server_logs/20171029: No matching job records located
/var/spool/torque/mom_logs/20171029: No matching job records located
/var/spool/torque/sched_logs/20171029: No matching job records located

Job: 62.localhost

10/30/2017 17:20:25  S    enqueuing into batch, state 1 hop 1
10/30/2017 17:20:25  S    Job Queued at request of wlandau@localhost, owner =
                          wlandau@localhost, job name = jobe945093c2e029c5de5619d6bf7922071,
                          queue = batch
10/30/2017 17:20:25  S    Job Modified at request of Scheduler@Haggunenon
10/30/2017 17:20:25  S    Exit_status=0 resources_used.cput=00:00:00 resources_used.mem=0kb
                          resources_used.vmem=0kb resources_used.walltime=00:00:00
10/30/2017 17:20:25  L    Job Run
10/30/2017 17:20:25  S    Job Run at request of Scheduler@Haggunenon
10/30/2017 17:20:25  S    Not sending email: User does not want mail of this type.
10/30/2017 17:20:25  S    Not sending email: User does not want mail of this type.
10/30/2017 17:20:25  M    job was terminated
10/30/2017 17:20:25  M    obit sent to server
10/30/2017 17:20:25  A    queue=batch
10/30/2017 17:20:25  M    scan_for_terminated: job 62.localhost task 1 terminated, sid=17917
10/30/2017 17:20:25  A    user=wlandau group=wlandau
                          jobname=jobe945093c2e029c5de5619d6bf7922071 queue=batch
                          ctime=1509398425 qtime=1509398425 etime=1509398425 start=1509398425
                          owner=wlandau@localhost exec_host=localhost/0 Resource_List.ncpus=1
                          Resource_List.neednodes=1 Resource_List.nodect=1
                          Resource_List.nodes=1 Resource_List.walltime=01:00:00 
10/30/2017 17:20:25  A    user=wlandau group=wlandau
                          jobname=jobe945093c2e029c5de5619d6bf7922071 queue=batch
                          ctime=1509398425 qtime=1509398425 etime=1509398425 start=1509398425
                          owner=wlandau@localhost exec_host=localhost/0 Resource_List.ncpus=1
                          Resource_List.neednodes=1 Resource_List.nodect=1
                          Resource_List.nodes=1 Resource_List.walltime=01:00:00 session=17917
                          end=1509398425 Exit_status=0 resources_used.cput=00:00:00
                          resources_used.mem=0kb resources_used.vmem=0kb
                          resources_used.walltime=00:00:00
```

## EDIT: jobs now hanging in `E`

After some tinkering, I am now using [these settings](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future.batchtools/blob/master/inst/templates/torque.tmpl). I have moved on to [this tiny pipeline workflow](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/blob/master/inst/examples/torque/run.R), where some TORQUE jobs wait for other TORQUE jobs to finish. Unfortunately, all the jobs hang in the `E` state, and any number of jobs more than 4 will just stay queued. To keep things from hanging indefinitely, I have to `sudo qdel -p` each one, which I think is causing legitimate problems with the project's filesystem as well as an inconvenience.

```
Job id                    Name             User            Time Use S Queue
------------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
113.localhost             ...b73ec2cda6dca wlandau         00:00:00 E batch          
114.localhost             ...b6c8e6da05983 wlandau         00:00:00 E batch          
115.localhost             ...9123b8e20850b wlandau         00:00:00 E batch          
116.localhost             ...e6d49a3d7d822 wlandau         00:00:00 E batch          
117.localhost             ...8c3f6cb68927b wlandau                0 Q batch          
118.localhost             ...40b1d0cab6400 wlandau                0 Q batch
```

`qmgr -c "list server"` shows

```
Server haggunenon
        server_state = Active
        scheduling = True
        max_running = 300
        total_jobs = 5
        state_count = Transit:0 Queued:1 Held:0 Waiting:0 Running:1 Exiting:3 
        acl_hosts = localhost
        managers = root@localhost
        operators = root@localhost
        default_queue = batch
        log_events = 511
        mail_from = adm
        query_other_jobs = True
        resources_assigned.ncpus = 4
        resources_assigned.nodect = 4
        scheduler_iteration = 600
        node_check_rate = 150
        tcp_timeout = 6
        mom_job_sync = True
        pbs_version = 2.4.16
        keep_completed = 0
        submit_hosts = SERVER
        allow_node_submit = True
        next_job_number = 119
        net_counter = 118 94 93
```

And `qmgr -c "list queue batch"`

```
Queue batch
        queue_type = Execution
        total_jobs = 5
        state_count = Transit:0 Queued:1 Held:0 Waiting:0 Running:0 Exiting:4 
        max_running = 300
        resources_max.ncpus = 4
        resources_max.nodes = 2
        resources_min.ncpus = 1
        resources_default.ncpus = 1
        resources_default.nodect = 1
        resources_default.nodes = 1
        resources_default.walltime = 01:00:00
        mtime = Wed Nov  1 07:40:45 2017
        resources_assigned.ncpus = 4
        resources_assigned.nodect = 4
        keep_completed = 0
        enabled = True
        started = True
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of `tracejob -n2 46`?

Answer (score 0):

`C` state means the job has completed and its status is kept in the system. Usually the status is kept after job completion for a period of time specified by the `keep_completed` parameter. However certain types of failure may result in the job being kept in this state to provide the information necessary to examine the cause of failure.

Check the output of `qstat -f 46` to see if there is anything indicating an error.

To tune the `keep_completed` parameter you can execute the following command to check the value of this parameter on your system.

```
qmgr -c "print queue batch keep_completed"
```

If you have administrative privileges on the Torque server you could also change this value with

```
qmgr -c "set queue batch keep_completed=120"
```

To keep jobs in completed state for 2 minutes after completion.

In general having `keep_completed` set is a useful feature. Advanced schedulers use the information on completed jobs to schedule around failures.

Comment: I added `qstat -f` output in the edit. I tried to make my reproducible example as minimal as possible, but really, I am using `batchtools` via [this R code](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/tree/master/inst/examples/torque). The trouble is that I am submitting sequences of jobs that depend on each other, so I need to be able to move on once the real work is finished.

Comment: I tried using `qmgr` to set `keep_completed=0`, but I am still having the same problem. Now, the job sits in `E` instead of `C`.

Comment: @landau could you please add a `tracejob` report as well?

Comment: Just added one at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @landau Looks like the job was terminated by the MOM daemon on the node. Resembles some known bugs. Please add Torque version reported by `qstat --version`.

Comment: I am using version: 2.4.16.

Comment: Also, please see the most recent edit at the bottom of the page (EDIT: jobs now hanging in `E`).

Comment: @landau This doesn't look good. You mentioned filesystem problems. Could it be the cause of the problem with Torque, not the result of it? I see you have posted also questions about SLURM. If you are the only user of the cluster perhaps smth. simple as GNU Parallel would be enough for your needs?

Comment: Quite the opposite, actually, I am developing an [R package for hpc](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake), and I need to test that it works on as many kinds of cluster as possible. That's the point of my questioning about TORQUE and SLURM.

Comment: Is there a `qmgr -c "set server ..."` or `qmgr -c "set queue batch ..."` option to let me tell TORQUE to clear out `E` jobs? Where are the files kept that are referenced by `qmgr -c "list server"` and `qmgr -c "list queue batch"`? I will shortly include my configurations at the end of the post.